# Difficulty connecting at 300Mbps with Channel Bonding

Tags: macbook-pro, network, wifi, macos

I'm trying to connect my MacBook Pro (early 2015) running High Sierra to my wifi at 300 Mbps but am only getting 150 Mbps.

I'm running a tp-link router flashed with one of the newer dd-wrt systems. The router status reports that it is transmitting at 300 mbps on the 2.4 and 5 GHz bands but my MacBook is only connecting at 150 mbps at most on either band. Also the Mac connection properties say that it is connected at channel 57 at 20 MHz. The router is set up for 40 MHz only.
My wifi analyzer app does indicate that the 2.4 amd 5 GHz signals have 2 channels each.

I think the router is set up correctly.
Is there something I need to do to have my MacBook connect at the higher 300Mbps speed?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out. It wasn't anything to do with my Macbook.

I had the 5GHz channel on the router set to the highest one (157). That apparently is a weaker signal.

I changed it to the lowest one (36) and I at least intermittently get a faster connection usually up to 270Mbps. Good enough.